# How to perform loop synchronously in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, synchronization

I am have 82 items in my collections i.e blogs.I want to write the whole into files in such a way that each file should have 10 blogs.So for my 82 I get 9 files.I wrote the code as ffollows

```
 blogList.forEach(function(i,v){
    async.waterfall([
        function (done) {
            if ((v !== 0) && (v%10 === 0)){
                var appendData = blogList.splice(0,10);
                if(v === 10) {
                    pageNum = 1;
                } else {
                    pageNum = v.toString()[0];
                }
                done('',appendData);
            }
        },function (testData,done) {
            try {
                var testingData = testData.toString();
                testData.forEach(function(k,l){
                    fs.readFile(tagFileReferance, function read(err, referanceData) {
                        if (err) {
                            helper.logs('prepareAmpBlogList','blog',err,'console'); 
                            throw err;
                        }
                        tagFileData = referanceData.toString();


                            var text = k.text;
                            text = text.replace('style','class');
                            modData = tagFileData.replace('_CLASS_',k.class).replace('_IMAGE_',k.image).replace('_TITLE_',k.title).replace('_DATE_',k.date).replace('_AUTHOR_',k.author).replace('_TEXT_',k.metaText).replace('_BLOG_ID_',k.blog_id);
                            replacedTagsData.push(modData);

                    });
              setTimeout(function () {
                    var newData = testList.toString();
                         var pageNum = v.toString()[0],                        
                         fileName = 'public/amp/test2/amp-blog-list-'+pageNum+'.html';
                             fs.writeFile(fileName, newData, function(err) {
                                 if(err) {
                                     return console.log(err);
                                }
                                 console.log("The file was saved!");
                             }); 
                     }, 500)
                });
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }],function (err) {
            helper.logs('prepareAmpBlogList','blog',err,'console');
            throw err;
        });
})
```

But only the first file is written the iteration is getting completed before the file write.Its async,can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: To offer you a good answer, we'd need to see what you're trying to do inside the loop.  As you have it now, that's makeup code because you're not doing anything different on each iteration of the loop and what you are doing affects the best way to write this code.  Please show real code for your problem, not just generic sample code.

Comment: hi jfriend..sure i will post.

Comment: Still waiting for the code and explanation of what you're actually trying to do.  Your opportunity for an answer from me expires in a short while (time to go to sleep). Of most importance is whether your multiple operations can be done in parallel or must be sequenced and what type of result you want when everything is done.

Answer (score 1):

**Use :**

`fs.writeFileSync` instead of `fs.writeFile` this will execute your code synchronously in node js.

**Note :**

As @jfriend00 has suggested:

> If this is a node.js server, you do not ever want to do synchronous
>   I/O except at server startup because it wrecks the scalability of the
>   single threaded server. Instead, one can sequence async operations or
>   monitor when they are done

It's not a good idea to go for sync functions until unless it's the only way.

Always find for async operations,that you can also achieve the same output with sync operation.

Comment: If this is a node.js server, you do not ever want to do synchronous I/O except at server startup because it wrecks the scalability of the single threaded server.  Instead, one can sequence async operations or monitor when they are done (depending upon the OP's requirement).

Comment: @jfriend00 , yes I know that's why node js is being used widely , but sometimes its user's requirement to make it synchronously.

Comment: Yet, you offer this as an answer without any explanation for when it would be a good or bad option and you don't make any effort to figure out what the OP is actually trying to do to see if  this would be a good option for them or not.  That's not what makes a good answer here.

Comment: @jfriend00, yes that's a good point, will take care this from now on. thank you very much.

Comment: @jfriend00 , please update the answer if you think its need to be. :)